# Using Stack & Queue in functional programming (javascript)

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I read some articles about functional programming, one of the criteria is "Given the same input, they always produce the same output". Base on this rule, how can i call push/pull/shift/unshift in javascript as the result should always change? Also, can you suggest how to apply stack/queue or workaround if i need to store the user input to an array. Thanks.

```
stack: []

recordData(value) {
    stack.push(value)
    ......
}
```

Comment: You can return a new stack/queue. With regard to your second question, depending on how you implement the stack/queue, it may already be an array.

Comment: @torazaburo, thank you for your reply. But it must violate the rule 'same input same output', for example, at the first time: stack.push(1), the output is [1]; at the second time: stack.push(1), the output is [1, 1]. How can i resolve this contradiction? Thanks

Comment: @torazaburo, besides, another rule is 'keep the variable immutable', but Stack & Queue seems to cause variable 'stack' always change. Therefore, i don't know can i use them under functional programming? Thanks

Comment: @Phil You don't contribute to the functional programming tag. I wonder why you voted for closing this question, since you apparently don't grok the given question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"same input same output"*
>
> ```
> let stack = []
> stack.push(1) // [1]
> stack.push(1) // [1,1]
> ```

Right. `Array.prototype.push` is a destructive function – it mutates its input. Your stack/queue would need to be implemented using pure functions – obviously ones that don't mutate the underlying data structure ...

---

**Binding agreement**

Before we continue, let's go over the `Stack` contract

```
// stack contract
stackIsEmpty(emptyStack)               => true
stackIsEmpty(stackPush(x, emptyStack)) => false
stackPop(stackPush(x, emptyStack))     => [x, emptyStack]
```

Any other use of these functions is *undefined* behaviour

- You must `stackPush` the first value onto `emptyStack`
- You must verify that a stack is not empty before calling `stackPop` on it

The implementation you see below is just *a* possible implementation. The point is the implementation of `Stack` doesn't matter so long as the contract is fulfilled.

---

***"But is it immutable though?"***

Yes, of course, but if you must see it to believe it, have a look for yourself. We create a sample stack, `s`, and then we call `stackPop` on it twice. **The result is the same for each call** because we implemented an immutable data structure.

```js
// stack data abstraction
const emptyStack = {}
const stackPush = (x, xs) => f => f(x,xs)
const stackPop = s => s((x,xs) => [x,xs])
const stackIsEmpty = s => s === emptyStack

// stackPush does not mutate emptyStack
let s = stackPush(1, emptyStack)
console.log(stackIsEmpty(emptyStack)) // true

// stackPop does not mutate s
let [test1, stack1] = stackPop(s)
console.log(test1, stack1) // 1 {}

// stackPop returning the same value for the same input, s
let [test2, stack2] = stackPop(s)
console.log(test2, stack2) // 1 {}
```

---

**Reverse a string using a stack**

Ok, so this is a really contrived example. I was having a little trouble coming up with a piece of code that demonstrated `push` and `pop` without overwhelming the reader.

So before anyone says it, yeah, this is a really dumb way to reverse a string, but that's besides the point. This is less about reversing the string and more about demonstrating the using pure functions with immutable data structures.

(bonus: most people don't think about them as such, but `String`s and `Number`s are immutable too!)

```js
// stack data abstraction
const emptyStack = {}
const stackPush = (x, xs) => f => f(x,xs)
const stackPop = s => s((x,xs) => [x,xs])
const stackIsEmpty = s => s === emptyStack

// some function using stack
const strReverse = str => {
  let load = (stack, str) => {
    if (str.length === 0)
      return stack
    else
      return load(stackPush(str[0], stack), str.substr(1))
  }
  let unload = (str, stack) => {
    if (stackIsEmpty(stack))
      return str
    else {
      let [char, nextStack] = stackPop(stack)
      return unload(str + char, nextStack)
    }
  }
  return unload('', load(emptyStack, str));
}

console.log(strReverse('foobar')) // 'raboof'
```

Comment: The `Stack` implementation is purposefully tricky. It could've easily been implemented using native `Array` but I am trying to remove focus from the Stack itself. I can't be clear enough on how non-important a specific implementation of `Stack` is as long as the contract holds.

Comment: Very useful, thanks!!

Comment: This comment just shows me at which point Functional Programming is foreign to me. I struggled for sometime to understand the code snippet. Can you recommend a resource that explores implementing traditional data structures using Functional Programming?

Comment: @KibongeMurphy When you set a property on an Object or slice an Array, do you think about *how* those actions are carried out? When you get in a car, turn the key in the ignition, press the gas pedal and turn the wheel, do you think about the gas pump, fuel injectors, and power steering motor? Do all cars implement these features in exactly the same way? The point of **abstraction** is to remove these details and concerns from the end user. As the driver, we only care that the car turns on and moves forward when the gas is pressed and stops when the brake is pressed, etc.

Comment: (cont'd) You might benefit from reading about [persistent data structures](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/persistent-data-structures/). On this site, I also have some posts on [functional style](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a633183%20functional).

Comment: Coincidentally, in [a question I answered today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65294475/633183) I show how to implement a functional-style linked list and include a OOP-style interface. This is a more real-world example compared to the minimalist stack above.