# Recurse in Linked List

Tags: javascript, recursion, linked-list

I have been practicing the linked list and wanted to implement the recurse on it, although in some cases I was able to implement it efficiently, in other cases I failed miserably at doing so. I would like to know a method to do the recursive so as not to have to use the "while" to go through the Linked List, I have used the recurse to go through the arrays but when I wanted to do it similar in this case it fails.

I don't have much experience in implementing recursion and wanted to apply it in this method to get more experience with it, but at least it helped me understand the Linked List more by having to do it over and over again. Thank you.

```js
class Node {
    // Accept arguments (the second one could be optional)
    constructor(data, next) {
        this.data = data; 
        this.next = next;

    }
    lastNode() { // new method that uses recursion
        return this.next?.lastNode() || this;
    }
}
class ListRecurse {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }
    add(data) {
        let newNode = new Node(data); // No second argument. It has a default value
        if (this.head === null) {
            this.head = newNode;
        } else {
            // The lastNode implementation uses recursion:
            this.head.lastNode().next = newNode;
        }
        this.size ++;
        return this; // to allow chaining
    }
    insertAdd(data, index) {
        if (index < 0 || index > this.size) {
            return null;
        }
        let newNode = new Node(data);
        let current = this.head;
        let prev;
        if (index === 0) {
            newNode.next = current;
            this.head = newNode;
        }
        else {
            for (let i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                prev = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            this.head.lastNode().next = current;
            prev.next = newNode;
        }
        this.size++;
        return this;
    }
    Print() {
        if (!this.size) {
            return null;
        }
        let current = this.head;
        let result = "";
        while(current) {
            result += current.data += "=>";
            current = current.next;
        }
        result += "X";
        return result;
        }
    DeletexData(data) {
           let current = this.head;
           let prev = null;
           if (this.head === null) {
               return null;
           }
           else if (current.data === data) {
               if(!prev) {
                   this.head = this.head.next;
               }
               else
               prev.next = current.next
           }
           return this.SearchDelete(data)
           }
    SearchDelete (data) {
            let current = this.head;
            let prev = null;
            while(current != null) {
                if (current.data === data) {
                    if (!current.next) prev.next = null
                else prev.next = current.next
                    this.size--;
                    return data;
                    }
                prev = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
        return null;
        }
    DeleteLastNode() {
        let current = this.head;
        if (current === null) {
            return 1
        }
        else if (current.next === null) {
            this.head = null;
        }
        else return this.LastNode()
        };
    LastNode() {
        let current = this.head;
        while (current.next.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = null;
        this.size--;
    }
    Search(data) {
        let current = this.head;
        if (current === null) {
            return null;
        }
        else 
        return this.RainbowSix(data)
    }
    RainbowSix(data) {
        let current = this.head; 
        while (current) {
            if (current.data === data) {
                return current;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
        return null;
    }
    Size(){
        return this.size
    }
}
let list = new ListRecurse();
list.add(1).add(2).add(3).add(44).add(66);
list.insertAdd(33,0)
list.DeleteLastNode()
console.log(list.Search(3))
console.log(list.Size())
console.log(list.Print())
console.log(list);
```

Comment: 'not to have to use the "while"' - but instead you want to recursively iterate a linked list, which is vastly inferior to a simple `while` loop?

Comment: @ASDFGerte: The question did mention doing this to practice recursion.

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not help.  It suggests a substantially different way to build your lists.

The idea is that recursion, although occasionally used with Object-Oriented (OO) systems, is much more closely tied to Functional Programming (FP).  So if you're going to use recursion on your lists, you might as well use it with FP lists.

Creating and manipulating lists is one of the strengths of FP, and we can write your code much more simply.  We create a bare list of one item, `42` by calling `const list1 = ins (42) (null)`.  We prepend that with `17` by calling `const list2 = ins (17) (list1)`.  Or we can write a whole chain of these like this:

```js
const list3 = ins (1) (ins (2) (ins (3) (ins (4) (ins (5) (null)))))
```

There are many differences from your code, but one of the most fundamental, is that this treats lists as immutable objects.  None of our code will *change* a list, it will just create a new one with the altered properties.

This is what `ins` might look like:

```js
const ins = (data) => (list) => 
  ({data, next: list})
```

We could choose to write this as `(data, list) => ...` instead of `(data) => (list) => ...`.  That's just a matter of personal preference about style.

But the basic construction is that a list is

- a value
- followed by either

  - another list
  - or `null`

Here is an implementation of these ideas:

```js
const ins = (data) => (list) => 
  ({data, next: list})

const del = (target) => ({data, next}) =>
  target == data ? next : next == null ? {data, next} : {data, next: del (target) (next)}  

const delLast = ({data, next}) =>
  next == null ? null : {data, next: delLast (next)}

const size = (list) => 
  list == null ? 0 : 1 + size (list.next)

const search = (pred) => ({data, next}) => 
  pred (data) ? {data, next} : next != null ? search (pred) (next) : null

const fnd = (target) => 
  search ((data) => data == target)

const print = ({data, next}) => 
  data + (next == null ? '' : ('=>' + print (next)))    

const list1 = ins (1) (ins (2) (ins (3) (ins (44) (ins (66) (null)))))
const list2 = ins (33) (list1)
const list3 = delLast (list2)

console .log (fnd (3) (list3))
console .log (size (list3))
console .log (print (list3))
console .log (list3)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note that all of these functions, except for `ins` and `find` are directly recursive.  They all call themselves.  And `find` simply delegates the recursive work to `search`.

It's too much to try to describe all of these functions, but lets look at two.  `print` is a simple function.

```js
const print = ({data, next}) => 
  data + (next == null ? '' : ('=>' + print (next)))
```

We build our output string by including our data followed by one of two things:

- an empty string, if `next` is `null`
- `'=>'` plus the recursive `print` call on `next`, otherwise.

`del` is a somewhat more complex function:

```
const del = (target) => ({data, next}) =>
  target == data
    ? next 
    : next == null 
      ? {data, next: null} 
      : {data, next: del (target) (next)}
```

We test if our current data is the target we want to delete.  If it is, we simply return the list stored as `next`.

If not, we check whether `next` is null.  If it is, we return (a copy of) the current list.  If it is not, then we return a new list formed by our current data and a recursive call to delete the target from the list stored as `next`.

---

If you want to learn more about these ideas, you probably want to search for "Cons lists" ("con" here is not the opposite of "pro", but has to do with "construct"ing something.)

I used different terms than are most commonly used there, but the ideas are much the same.  If you run across the terms `car` and `cdr`, they are equivalent to our `data` and `next`, respectively.

Comment: bang up job here, Scott. I came to say pretty much the same thing but was a little late to the show! I added a portion to my answer that shows how the OOP interface can be added with ease.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on this answer as Scott made his post, making most of this information redundant. There is a portion which shows how to couple OOP-style with functional (persistent) data structures which you should find helpful.

Similar to Scott's answer, we start by writing plain functions, no classes or methods. I'm going to place mine in a module named `list.js` -

```js
// list.js
import { raise } from "./func"

const nil =
  Symbol("nil")

const isNil = t =>
  t === nil

const node = (value, next) =>
  ({ node, value, next })

const singleton = v =>
  node(v, nil)

const fromArray = a =>
  a.reduceRight((r, _) => node(_, r), nil)

const insert = (t, v, i = 0) =>
  isNil(t)
    ? singleton(v)
: i > 0
    ? node(t.value, insert(t.next, v, i - 1))
: node(v, t)

const last = t =>
  isNil(t)
    ? raise("cannot get last element of empty list")
: isNil(t.next)
    ? t.value
: last(t.next)

const search = (t, q) =>
  isNil(t)
    ? undefined
: t.value === q
    ? t
: search(t.next, q)

const size = t =>
  isNil(t)
    ? 0
    : 1 + size(t.next)

const toString = t =>
  isNil(t)
    ? "Nil"
    : `${t.value}->${toString(t.next)}`

const toArray = t =>
  isNil(t)
    ? []
    : [ t.value, ...toArray(t.next) ]
```

Now we can implement our OOP-style, `List` interface. This gives you the chaining behaviour you want. Notice how the methods are simple wrappers around the plain functions we wrote earlier -

```js
// list.js (continued)

class List
{ constructor(t = nil)
  { this.t = t }

  isNil()
  { return isNil(this.t) }

  size()
  { return size(this.t) }

  add(v)
  { return new List(node(v, this.t)) }

  insert(v, i)
  { return new List(insert(this.t, v, i)) }

  toString()
  { return toString(this.t) }
}
```

Finally, make sure to export the parts of your module

```js
// list.js (continued)

export { nil, isNil, node, singleton, fromArray, insert, last, search, size, toArray, toString }

export default List
```

The `List` interface allows you to do things in the familiar OOP ways -

```js
import List from "../list"

const t = (new List).add(3).add(2).add(1)

console.log(t.toString())
// 1->2->3->Nil

console.log(t.insert(9, 0).toString())
// 9->1->2->3->Nil

console.log(t.isNil())
// false

console.log(t.size())
// 3
```

Or you can import your module and work in a more functional way -

```js
import * as list from "../list"

const t = list.fromArray([1, 2, 3])


console.log(list.toString(t))
// 1->2->3->Nil

console.log(list.isNil(t))
// true

console.log(list.size(t))
// 3
```

I think the important lesson here is that the module functions can be defined once, and then the OOP interface can be added afterwards.

---

A series of tests ensures the information in this answer is correct. We start writing the plain function tests -

```js
// list_test.js

import List, * as list from "../list.js"
import * as assert from '../assert.js'
import { test, symbols } from '../test.js'

await test("list.isNil", _ => {
  assert.pass(list.isNil(list.nil))
  assert.fail(list.isNil(list.singleton(1)))
})

await test("list.singleton", _ => {
  const [a] = symbols()
  const e = list.node(a, list.nil)
  assert.equal(e, list.singleton(a))
})

await test("list.fromArray", _ => {
  const [a, b, c] = symbols()
  const e = list.node(a, list.node(b, list.node(c, list.nil)))
  const t = [a, b, c]
  assert.equal(e, list.fromArray(t))
})

await test("list.insert", _ => {
  const [a, b, c, z] = symbols()
  const t = list.fromArray([a, b, c])
  assert.equal(list.fromArray([z,a,b,c]), list.insert(t, z, 0))
  assert.equal(list.fromArray([a,z,b,c]), list.insert(t, z, 1))
  assert.equal(list.fromArray([a,b,z,c]), list.insert(t, z, 2))
  assert.equal(list.fromArray([a,b,c,z]), list.insert(t, z, 3))
  assert.equal(list.fromArray([a,b,c,z]), list.insert(t, z, 99))
  assert.equal(list.fromArray([z,a,b,c]), list.insert(t, z, -99))
})

await test("list.toString", _ => {
  const e = "1->2->3->Nil"
  const t = list.fromArray([1,2,3])
  assert.equal(e, list.toString(t))
  assert.equal("Nil", list.toString(list.nil))
})

await test("list.size", _ => {
  const [a, b, c] = symbols()
  assert.equal(0, list.size(list.nil))
  assert.equal(1, list.size(list.singleton(a)))
  assert.equal(2, list.size(list.fromArray([a,b])))
  assert.equal(3, list.size(list.fromArray([a,b,c])))
})

await test("list.last", _ => {
  const [a, b, c] = symbols()
  const t = list.fromArray([a,b,c])
  assert.equal(c, list.last(t))
  assert.throws(Error, _ => list.last(list.nil))
})

await test("list.search", _ => {
  const [a, b, c, z] = symbols()
  const t = list.fromArray([a, b, c])
  assert.equal(t, list.search(t, a))
  assert.equal(list.fromArray([b, c]), list.search(t, b))
  assert.equal(list.singleton(c), list.search(t, c))
  assert.equal(undefined, list.search(t, z))
})

await test("list.toArray", _ => {
  const [a,b,c] = symbols()
  const e = [a,b,c]
  const t = list.fromArray(e)
  assert.equal(e, list.toArray(t))
})
```

Next we ensure the `List` interface behaves accordingly -

```js
// list_test.js (continued)

await test("List.isNil", _ => {
  assert.pass((new List).isNil())
  assert.fail((new List).add(1).isNil())
})

await test("List.size", _ => {
  const [a,b,c] = symbols()
  const t1 = new List
  const t2 = t1.add(a)
  const t3 = t2.add(b)
  const t4 = t3.add(c)
  assert.equal(0, t1.size())
  assert.equal(1, t2.size())
  assert.equal(2, t3.size())
  assert.equal(3, t4.size())
})

await test("List.toString", _ => {
  const t1 = new List
  const t2 = (new List).add(3).add(2).add(1)
  assert.equal("Nil", t1.toString())
  assert.equal("1->2->3->Nil", t2.toString())
})

await test("List.insert", _ => {
  const t = (new List).add(3).add(2).add(1)
  assert.equal("9->1->2->3->Nil", t.insert(9, 0).toString())
  assert.equal("1->9->2->3->Nil", t.insert(9, 1).toString())
  assert.equal("1->2->9->3->Nil", t.insert(9, 2).toString())
  assert.equal("1->2->3->9->Nil", t.insert(9, 3).toString())
  assert.equal("1->2->3->9->Nil", t.insert(9, 99).toString())
  assert.equal("9->1->2->3->Nil", t.insert(9, -99).toString())
})
```

---

Dependencies used in this post -

`func.raise` - allows you to raise an error using an expression instead of a `throw` statement

```js
// func.js

const raise = (msg = "", E = Error) => // functional throw
  { throw E(msg) }

// ...

export { ..., raise }
```

Comment: As seems to happen so often, we're on the same wavelength.  I had to stop where I was for time constraints, so I'm really glad to see something that expands the ideas.

Comment: I love how simply you build the OOP version atop the FP one.  I don't usually think to do this.  Also, is `test.symbols` just something like `function * () {while (true) {yield Symbol()}}`?  It makes sense, but I've never thought to use an infinite generator in combination with destructuring that way -- very clean.

Comment: You guessed `test.symbols` exactly. I haven’t found a use for it outside of writing tests, but it sure is handy in that domain. Thanks for the comments :D